# CSS hover change other class

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to change the class of an other object when I hover over an object?
A menu-item has to change when I hover over the sub-menu.
I have;

```
ul.menu .menulink {
  padding:0px 13px 0px;
  height:23px;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:auto;
}
ul.menu ul li:hover .menulink{
  color:#002d36;
  background-image:none; 
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

HTML;

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menulink"><span>Main menu item</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also tried jQuery;

```
    $('ul.menu ul li').mouseover(function(){
        $('.menulink').css('color', '#002d36');
        $('.menulink').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    });
    $('ul.menu ul li').mouseout(function(){
        $('.menulink').css('color', '');
        $('.menulink').css('background-color', '');
    });
```

But that changes the other main menu items aswell..
Anyone knows how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `.menulink`, a sub-element of the li? Can you show the HTML as well?

Comment: Is purely CSS3 an option?  Or do you want to do CSS2-compatible browsers as well?

Comment: I want CSS2 for the old browsers aswell. I'll try to edit the message and put the html in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in css you can't select objects backwards. I wrote yesterday a little script in jq that should help.

```
$('.menu ul li').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent('ul').parent('li').find('a.menulink').css('color', '#002d36');
},
function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').parent('li').find('a.menulink').css('color', '#F00');
});
```

EDIT:

this works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/YBJHP/

Comment: I don't really understand how I should use it, I'm pretty new to jQuery :)

Comment: sorry, heres a detailed doc 
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

just paste it after jq lib (http://jquery.com/) and try it out.

Comment: I know the basics of jQuery, the hover too, but the script you gave didn't work. I'm new to the parent and child atributes.
There is more information in the original post, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible by using pure CSS. I recommend using jQuery. You can do it very easily with jQuery:

```
  $('.menulink').hover( 
    function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#New-Color-In-HEX');
    },
    function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#Old-Color-In-HEX');
    }
  );
```

Comment: This works, but it changes all the mainmenu-items, is there a way to only change the parent mainmenu item?

Comment: @Jay: There should be better solutions, but what I can think of right now is that you'd have to define a specific class for your parent main menu items. (duplicate the css styles in a new class called `.mainmenulink`) and use `$('.mainmenulink'.hover(...`

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it with pure css. I'm guessing you are trying to do dropdowns with css. You may want to look at suckerfish:

http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I already have a JavaScript dropdown-menu which works perfect, I only want the main item to have a white background when you hover over the sub-items. Is that really not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is keep the parent highlighted as you navigate through a sub-menu/sub-menus. To achieve this you need to apply the hover styles to the `<li>`'s rather than the `<a>`'s. An example of this in action can be seen in [one of the suckerfish demos](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/).